# Probability to have few records in all suffixes of a permutation

Tags: probability, permutations

I have a random permutation $\pi$ of size $n$, and for any $1\leq i\leq n$, I write $x_{i}$ for the number of records in $\pi[i..n]$ (that is, $x_{i}$ is the number of positions $k$, $i\leq k\leq n$ such that $\pi[k]\geq \pi[k']$ for $i\leq k'\leq k$). I then say that $\pi$ is "$\alpha$-bad" if some $x_{i}$ is larger than $\alpha \log n$ (i.e., **some suffix of $\pi$ has more than $\alpha \log n$ records**).

I am trying to prove the following conjecture:
**there exists some $\alpha$ such that the probability for a permutation to be $\alpha$-bad tends to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity.**

The idea is that the number of records in a permutation tends to a normal distribution with expected value $\log n$ and square variance $\log n$, so basically the probability is extremely low to have, say $4 \log n$ records in $\pi$. But here we're talking about $n$ different permutations (the suffixes of $\pi$), that are not independent, so I have no clue on how to bound the worst of this series.

In particular, I can show with Berry-Essen that the probability that a size-$n$ permutation has more than $\log n + x$ records is upper-bounded by $\frac{C_0}{\sqrt{\log n}}+f(x)$ (with  $f$ exponentially small), but if I take $n$ of these I get to multiply by $n$ and this does not tend to 0 anymore...

Any help is appreciated !

Edit: regarding increasing subsequences: $x_i$ corresponds to the length of the "greedy" increasing subsequence from position $i$, where, at each step, the next element is the first available that has a larger value. This strategy is not optimal in general, so the $\sqrt{n}$ bound for longest increasing subsequence does not hold here.

Edit 2: Aiming at disproving the conjecture, we could also take the worst number of records among $\sqrt{n}$ independent permutations of size $\sqrt {n}$, then it might be easier to get a larger lower-bound.

Comment: Where is $j$ used?

Comment: Is $\max_i x_i$ actually the length of the longest increasing subsequence in $\pi$?

Comment: If so, the order of it should be $\sqrt{n}$. See, e.g, Baik, Jinho, Percy Deift, and Kurt Johansson. "On the distribution of the length of the longest increasing subsequence of random permutations." Journal of the American Mathematical Society 12.4 (1999): 1119-1178.

Comment: ($j$ was a typo, edited away) and no: each $x_i$ indeed corresponds to an increasing subsequence, but there's little chance that the longest one appears in any $x_i$

Comment: I got it now, thanks!